# how to search specific epoch format timestamp in wireshark

Tags: filter, timestamp, wireshark

in Wireshark it provides a few options to display the time.

but I just want to see the epoch Unix timestamp, is anyone know how to display this? there are a few options for showing the absolute timestamp but not for epoch Unix timestamp.

also, if possible, how can use the display filter to display the data with a specific timestamp?

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to add a column for Epoch Time is to open a capture file, expand the Frame details in the Packet details pane, then right-click on the Epoch Time field and choose, *"Apply as Column"*.  You can then drag & drop the column to your preferred location.

You can also add it through the *"Edit -> Preferences -> Columns"* dialog.  Click the `+` button to add a new column, rename the title to "Epoch Time", set the Type to "Custom" and the Fields to "frame.time_epoch" (no quotes).  Drag & drop the column to the order in the list you prefer.

*how can use the display filter to display the data with a specific timestamp?*
Whether you add a column to display it or not, you can always apply a display filter for the field.  For example, `frame.time_epoch == 1603985924.375120000`.  You can type it manually in the display filter text box or right-click on the field in the packet details pane and choose, *"Apply [or Prepare] as Filter"*.  Preparing the filter allows you to construct more complicated filters by appending more filters until you've constructed the entire filter of interest.  This might be useful in this case when filtering packets that fall within a specific time range, e.g., `(frame.time_epoch >= 1603985924.375120000) && (frame.time_epoch <= 1603985933.427006000)`.